# Are Blue Shift and Opposing Force "canon"?

Tags: half-life, half-life-series

I know that the two of them are independently developed from Half-Life itself, and based on events that took place during Half-Life, but are the two games considered part of the official Half-Life Canon, or has Valve not formally adopted them as part of the backstory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no official Half-Life canon. Valve have not and do not intend to define what is and what isn't canon. Series' writer Marc Laidlaw stated that they do not "get involved in issues of canonicity", that "canon itself is non-canon", and that there is "no official stance".

Source: http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Half-Life_Wiki:Canon

Answer (score 1):

I'd say they're both canon. I'm no expert, but I have played all 3 games and you see Gordon in both of the expansions.
Blue Shift, you see him being dragged by the HECU soldiers on the way to the crusher, and in Opposing Force you see him jumping into the Xen portal. I'd consider them both canon.
(Personal canon, while the creators have opted out of saying whether they are, I think the common consensus from the fanbase is that they're both canon.)

Answer (score -4):

BS is canon. Valve made it, Barney is in HL2.

Chanced are, OF is as well. Nothing is contradicted, Adrian meets G-Man, it's safe to assume it is.

Comment: The reoccurrence of characters is not what makes something canon.

Comment: Gearbox made Blue Shift